# add select2 class dynamically to current clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I added select2 class dynamically to current clicked an element, but search box comes after the 2nd click. It should come on the first click on the element.

Ex:

```
$(document).on('click', 'select', function () {             
    $(this).select2();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide us with a working snippet of your problem?

Comment: It works https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/z5ogefz8/

Comment: try replacing line `$(this).select2();` with `$(this).select2().select2('open');`  but why you need such behavior? Logically all the select boxes should gets converted to `select2` on page load itself to have good UX. https://jsfiddle.net/z5ogefz8/2/

Answer (score 2):

After the select2 has been initialized then we can call it again with the command `.select2('open')`

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'select', function() {
  var select2_open;
  $(this).select2().select2('open');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://select2.github.io/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>

<select class="select">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.select').select2();
$(document).on('click', 'select', function() {
  $(this).select2();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://select2.github.io/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>

<select class="select">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add `onclick`

Just `$('select').select2();`

https://jsfiddle.net/vandolphreyes29/z5ogefz8/7/

Comment: I think you need to read the question again. He's doing it this way for dynamically created elements.